# Spring REST - Post when Binary coming in

Tags: spring

I have been working mostly on get requests and generally use RestClient to test any web service. Usually perform a GET for object.

Now I am attempting to do my first POST. For the GET requests, I have been passing a query string and parsing that way  Now this web service is accepting many field. Ordin

1. Does a POST always have to receive an object versus a string or even a query string? Probably a dumb question.
2. When the object comes in since one of the fields is a byte array do I have to do anything special in terms of catching the field in a bytearray converter. Can the post accept multiple variables such as String, MultiPart

Answer (score 0):

Post receives whatever you want it to receive.  It is completely setup through your method definition

```
void doRestPost(String foo)
void doAnotherRestPost(MyObject bar)
```

Here is an example that might help https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase

Another post that is helpful:
[What is the difference between a HTTP-Get and HTTP-POST and why is HTTP-POST weaker in terms of security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080863/what-is-the-difference-between-a-http-get-and-http-post-and-what-is-http-post-sec)

According to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html you should be find with a byte array.

Comment: Thanks. One question. Can a image be passed in as part of a string like I was doing with byte arrays.

Comment: you can convert a string to a byte array ... why do you want to?

Comment: One of the parameters coming is a binary image. I am not clear how the controller would receive this. Png File. Basically a file is submitted to the service along with other parameters. I take that file and email that to a list of recipients.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html ~ multi part upload ~ and please make my answer as the solution :)